# Is a <= a + 1 a good practice in VHDL?

Tags: hardware, vhdl, xilinx, hdl, modelsim

If I write the statement to assign a to be a+1 in a VHDL process, is it a good practice?

I am confused about this because the simulator works fine, but when I try to implement it in FPGA the synthesis tool complains about creating latches.

What does this mean?

Comment: Latches are implied if it sometimes holds the value, but you have not specified it in a clocked block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should do such a statement only in a clocked process. if you want to have it synthesised, an additional initialisation (reset) is suggested. might look as follows:

```
process(clk, reset)
begin
   if reset='1' then
      a <= 0;
   elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      a <= a + 1;
   end if;
end process;
```

Answer (score 5):

In a clocked process, this is fine. Anywhere else, probably not.

Answer (score 3):

Do it in a clocked process, that's fine.  What it means is "the next value of `a` should be the current value of `a` +1"

---

If you do it as a continuous assignment (outside of any process), what you are saying is "a is always getting a+1 assigned to it" which is a self-referential loop!

If you include `a` in the sensitivity list of an enabled process, you get the same effect

```
process (en, a)
begin
   if en = '1' then 
      a <= a + 1;
   end if;
end process;
```

(You can use this form to create transparent latches:

```
process (en, insig)
begin
   if en = '1' then 
      a <= insig;
   end if;
end process;
```

)

---

If you do it in a non-clocked process, which is *not* sensitive to `a`:

```
process (en)
begin
   if en = '1' then 
      a <= a + 1;
   end if;
end process;
```

You will create a positive-edge-triggered latch, as `a` needs to keep its value between changes of `en`.  Effectively, `en` becomes a clock to a d-type flipflop.

Comment: Actually, in your last example Altera's synthesis tool will implement `a` as a register clocked by `en`. (Which is arguably correct, no need to check for en'event since there's no asynchronous reset.) Still this is probably not a good idea!